# How can I translate _multiple_ strings at once?

Tags: chatgpt-api

I'm researching an idea of translating html page from one language to another -- to translate visible text, if be more specific. I already split html to markup and text chunks, and now I need to translate text by ChatGPT. But for my idea I need to translate N pieces of text strictly to N pieces. Currently my best experiments:

> "Translate to English this N lines line by line:  ["line1","line2",...,"lineN"]"

But for some widely use phrases ChatGPT can't resist the temptation to join two strings into one. For example, it will join phrases "If you don't want to receive this emails click this", "link" with high probability. Of cause, in my case any mismatch between number of texts and number of translations is fatal.

Is there any method to force ChatGPT to transform N strings to N strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found appropriate query:

```
Translate this N strings to <language> preserving its number: [ 1. "Line1", 2. "Line2", ... , N. "LineN"]
```

It produces stable output like:

```
1. "Translation1"
2. "Translation2"
...
N. "TranslationN"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need as well. I want to translate a localized file that contains a large amount of fragmented text. I have tried using string arrays, formats with line numbers, and various prompts, but unfortunately, ChatGPT 3.5 turbo can only handle input texts with a length of less than 500 characters while preserving the format. If there is a large amount of text and the meaning is interconnected between the texts, ChatGPT may not be able to handle it correctly.

For translating text in an array format, your prompt could be something like: "You will receive a string array, and you need to translate each string into Chinese while strictly preserving the format of the string array. Do not change the order or merge sentences."

Additionally, using numbering formats such as 1. 2. 3. often yields better results compared to string arrays. And providing an example could be helpful, but these measures may not ensure stable handling of large amounts of text exceeding 1000 characters by ChatGPT. I believe this might be the limit of its capabilities. GPT-4 would likely perform better, butI do not have access to it, and the pricing might be challenging to accept.